# error message : "com.googlebitcoin.core.ProtocolException:Peer does not have a copy of the block chain"?

Tags: transactions

I sent a Bitcoin yesterday at 8pm using Hive and this morning an error message popped up

```
com.googlebitcoin.core.ProtocolException:Peer does not have a copy of the block chain
```

Does it normally take this long for the transaction?  It still appears as pending in Hive.

To make matters worse the transaction is not found on blockchain.info.

Can someone help figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

ok, so this problem resolved itself. I think the main reason it occurred was because the transaction fee was to low.

So there should be more information out there regarding the fact if the fee is too low payment will get delayed by two whole days ?

or

Maybe it was because I held on to Hive on my desktop ?